# Restarting multiple mac computers with terminal

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, terminal, applescript

How do you restart multiple mac computers that are on the same network with terminal? I know the ssh command to login to one computer but I want to be able to send a reboot command to multiple computers at the same time from a server machine. I would like to create a applescript and then just run it from the server. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a for loop that loops through a list of your Mac's IP addresses and sends this command to each IP for each item in the list.

```
ssh $ip "/sbin/shutdown -r now"
```